# sql find all instances where all are part of distinct group

Tags: sql, function, subquery, aggregate, distinct

I'm sure a similar question to this has already been asked and answered, but I haven't been able to find anything in search, please be gentle.

I would like to know all the names of faculty members in a database who teach in every room of a building. The tables are very bare, but they are:

```
class:
+--------+---------+------+------+
| cname  | meetsat | room | fid  |
+--------+---------+------+------+
| class  | 8       | R128 |    5 |
| class2 | 9       | R129 |    6 |
| class3 | 9       | R128 |    5 |
+--------+---------+------+------+

faculty:
+-----+---------------+--------+
| fid | fname         | deptid |
+-----+---------------+--------+
|   5 | i.teach       |    999 |
|   6 | other guy     |    998 |
|   8 | another woman |    997 |
+-----+---------------+--------+
```

Through discussion with other users so far, I have:

```
(SELECT f.fname
FROM faculty f, class c
WHERE f.fid = c.fid)
UNION
(select c.fid
from class c
group by c.fid
having count(distinct room) = (select count(distinct c2.room) from class 
c2));
```

current output:
    +-----------+
    | fname     |
    +-----------+
    | i.teach   |
    | other guy |
    +-----------+

desired output should be:

```
+---------+
| fname   |
+---------+
| i.teach |
+---------+
```

I think I only need to join correctly. The course materials I have are extremely bare-bones and don't offer much in concept instruction, so I don't know who to apply them in different situations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division

Comment: I'm not sure what this took me to. Are these similar questions that have been asked before?

Comment: When posting questions asking for query help, please include sample table data and an expected output from the query. Even better, create a salfiddle (Google it) and post it up for us to edit and enhance.. Your post is a bit skinny on detail for easily verifiable solutions to be created

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard. I often worry about getting to 'wordy' with my submissions. I will update with more detail.

Comment: @CaiusJard I have updated my original post with a more detailed description of my scenario. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You wouldn't use union here. Union is for appending resultsets where the columns are the same I.e, it causes more rows to appear. What you say you want is more data columns tacking onto the right hand side of existing rows.. that's a join. Remember: union causes data to extend vertically. Join causes it to extend horizontally

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for that. That last sentence is poignant, yet extremely useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that may do what you require, implementing your algorithm of comparing counts. It is an alternative to the HAVING posted by Gordon

```
SELECT * FROM

  (SELECT count(distinct room) as countAllRooms FROM class) ar
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT c.fid, count(distinct c.room) as countRoomsPerTeacher FROM class c GROUP BY c.fid) rpt
  ON
    rpt.countRoomsPerTeacher = ar.countAllRooms


  INNER JOIN 
  faculty f
  ON
    f.fid = rpt.fid
```

In relation to your query on Gordon's answer, the safest way to join the faculty table:

```
Select * from faculty inner join 
(
select c.fid
from class C
group by c.fid
having count(distinct room) = (select count(distinct c2.room) from class c2)
) ff 
on ff.fid = faculty.fid
```

I wouldn't normally format an sql like this but I've done this deliberately to show the bits I added and which bits were Gordon's

You should avoid trying to join the he faculty table into the inner query that does the grouping as it will force you to add more columns to your select list, which forces you to add more to your group by, which breaks your counting,, better to consider Gordon's query a "faculty finder" that runs in isolation as a sub query and is joined later

Comment: I tried entering your code into my command line and got an error.  "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'f.fid' in 'field list'". the second block you provided ran without error but produced an empty set.

Comment: Which query is giving the error? The second query code produces an empty set because none of your teachers in the example data teach in all rooms. Fid 5 only ever teaches in room 128, room 129 is only used by fid6. No one uses both rooms

Comment: wow... so the data i was given was flawed? I updated row three and now your first example is working (second example is not though). I need to reverse engineer it to understand all of the pieces, but now that I see the solution I'm sure I can work it back. Thank you so much for your information and continued dialogue!

Comment: Corrected a couple of minor code flaws that may hinder your reverse understanding. I'll add an explanation to help after I test that one that you didn't get any joy with

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `having`:

```
select c.fid
from class c
group by c.fid
having count(distinct c.room) = (select count(distinct c2.room) from class c2);
```

Getting the name is just a matter of joining in the `faculty` table.

Comment: Okay, I can't tell yet but I think this is the correct answer. I need to go back and research how to properly join the faculty table. Also, just in case anyone reads this in the future, I needed to change lines 2 and 3 to 'class c' and 'group by c.fid'. Not @Gordon Linoff's fault, but I got stuck on it for a few minutes lol

Comment: I wondered about doing this, extended my wondering to whether there needed to be any coordination between the two queries.. as it stands, it looks to me like your count query essentially just provides a constant. I couldn't work out from the op's question whether there was more than one set of classroooms

Answer (score 0):

What about inner join  or I didn’t understand your question.

```
Select f.name from faculty f inner join class c on f.fid=c.fid
```

Comment: this actually got me really close! it gave me all of the names of teachers who teach each class in the building (room 1, room 2, etc.) My original question was for finding only the teachers that teach in every room. My thought process was that if the distinct numbers of c.fid1 (teacher 1) is the same as the distinct numbers of room numbers then that would trigger the select i wanted. An example would be teacher 1 appears in c.fid 4 times and there are 4 distinct rooms in c.room, so that fid (and the corresponding fname) would be extracted from the faculty table. Hopefully that made sense lol

Comment: You have to use “having” if you want to compare between counts